# Arquillian cannot find addAsWebInfResource method

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I can't find this method, but all examples show it:

```
return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class).addPackage(Baby.class.getPackage())
                .addAsManifestResource("jbossas-ds.xml", "jbossas-ds.xml")
                //.addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml");
```

What do I need to do to make this method work `addAsWebInfResource`?  I only have `addAsResource` and `addAsManifsetResource`, but not the `addAsWebInfResource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ShrinkWrap package isn't a web archive:

```
ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
```

Should be:

```
ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
```

This should provide you those methods.